# How to set default disk image format in Cockpit/QEMU

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, cockpit, debian-bookworm

I create my virtual machines on Debian 12 with Linux Cockpit 287-1 which uses QEMU/KVM for virtualization. If I create a VM, the default disk format is always in RAW-format. However, due to some functionalities such as creating (live) snapshots in Cockpit and smaller disk images, I prefer QCOW2 over RAW as the image format (I'm aware of certain downsides of this format).

Currently, after I set up a VM, I shut down my server, convert the RAW image to QCOW2 by hand and have to use `virsh edit` to edit some properties, such as the path to the QCOW2-image and the disk driver.

For me, it would be way more convenient to have QCOW2 as the default image format for new VMs, however, I cannot find any settings in cockpit to set the format. In the `qemu.conf` I can find three settings which are set to raw, but commented out:

```
#save_image_format = "raw"
#dump_image_format = "raw"
#snapshot_image_format = "raw"
```

However, I'm not sure, if these are the settings I have to change and I haven't found any information on the internet. The config settings have explanations such as:

```
# save_image_format is used when you use 'virsh save' or 'virsh managedsave'
# at scheduled saving, and it is an error if the specified save_image_format
# is not valid, or the requested compression program can't be found.
```

but I barely used the command line in the past for qemu and I am not sure if I am on the right track and if it is sufficient to simply change this three settings (without disturbing my other VMs).

So how can I specify the default VM image format and set it to QCOW2 when I create machines in Linux Cockpit?

Comment: Bookworm version of cockpit-machines is 288 - in version 289 of cockpit-machines, you can select qcow2 or raw format for the storage (qcow2 is actually the default selection) - you could consider bookworm-backports repo, at least for cockpit?